# how to change user agent in selenium with .net

Tags: .net, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

I want to test a web app written in .NET with different agents (iPhone, iPad, Android), I'm using NUnit for the tests and Selenium.

Anyone has a sample to change the agent (for example for iPad or iPhone) in Selenium with c# or VB?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Example UA (You may need Google yourself to find the ones suit your purpose):

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25

**C# Firefox:**

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

**C# Chrome:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**C# PhantomJS** (untested code):

```
PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25");
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
```

**C# IE:** Sorry, I don't think this is possible natively from Selenium.

Further reading: [Set user agent using Selenium WebDriver C# and Ruby](http://yizeng.me/2013/08/10/set-user-agent-using-selenium-webdriver-c-and-ruby/)

Answer (score 2):

In c#:

```
public static FirefoxProfile myFireProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
myFireProfile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10");
public IWebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(myFireProfile);
```