# Initialising a Webdriver UserAgent in chrome does not seem to emulate an iPhone

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

When I set my driver to run as an iPhone using the UserAgent ruby gem (webdriver-user-agent) in Chrome or Firefox, the screen does not appear as it would when I do this manually on Chrome/Firefox and all the (mobile) elements on screen are not visible.

Does this User Agent work for selenium or just watir? If it does, is there anything I can do to make this work? Code below:

```
when 'iphone'

@driver = Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(:browser => :chrome, :agent => :iphone, :orientation => :portrait)
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium should be able able to handle it, no need to use third party gems.

I answered a C# version before, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18004643/1177636).

Here's the Ruby version:

**Firefox**

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['general.useragent.override'] = 'YOUR_UA_STRING'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

**Chrome**

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--user-agent=YOUR_UA_STRING]
```

Please remember to escape the space in string array, for example:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0\ (iPhone;\ CPU\ iPhone\ OS\ 5_0\ like\ Mac\ OS\ X)\ AppleWebKit/534.46\ (KHTML,\ like\ Gecko)\ Version/5.1\ Mobile/9A334\ Safari/7534.48.3]
```

**PhantomJS**

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs('phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent' => 'YOUR_UA_STRING')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => capabilities
```

**IE**

Not available natively from Selenium

Comment: OK, so I seem to have this working (see code below), but it still doesn't display the elements that it should for a mobile and as chrome does when you manually set the same User Agent when 'iphone'
        `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3']`

Comment: @user2664501: You need to escape the spaces in string array. `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0\ (iPhone;\ CPU\ iPhone\ OS\ 5_0\ like\ Mac\ OS\ X)\ AppleWebKit/534.46\ (KHTML,\ like\ Gecko)\ Version/5.1\ Mobile/9A334\ Safari/7534.48.3]`

Comment: Hi - I tried this exactly as specified, but it still doesn't work. It still shows the desktop version when running via selenium, however, when manually overridig the user agent (with iPhone 5) in Chrome, it displays the mobile version as expected.

Comment: added a similar version for Android with a similar result (and multiple tabs opening on the selenium browser) `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %w[--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0\ (Linux;\ U\ Android 4.0.2\ en-us\ Galaxy Nexus Build/ICL53F)\ AppleWebKit/534.30\ (KHTML,\ like\ Gecko)\ Version/4.0\ Mobile Safari/534.30]`

Comment: @user2664501: Use your Selenium opened browser, go to http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/ and see what shows up.

Comment: Thanks - user agent details as follows: Your User Agent String is:
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3`
Your IP Address: 212.159.172.38

Comment: @user2664501: This is your expected one, i.e I believe you have successfully changed the your user agent using Selenium. For example, use this Selenium opened browser, go to stackoverflow.com, if the user agent has been correctly set, you should see mobile view. Then go to your application, if it's not in mobile view, it means something wrong with your application rather than user agent, which is a different question to ask.

Comment: OK I understand that, however, if I set the User Agent manually in chrome then I get the expected (mobile) result. Its just when I do it via the selenium browser that there is a problem, leading me to believe its a selenium problem

Comment: @user2664501: First, when you manually did it, was it a clean Chrome with fresh profile? If not, please try again. Also, what if you try it on Firefox, same behaviour or anything else? It could be something with Selenium or ChromeDriver, but it's unlikely an issue with Selenium's ability of setting user agent.