# How to change selenium user agent in selenium-webdriver nodejs land?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I'm in javascript + mocha + node land.

I have tried setting userAgent and 'user-agent' as keys on capabilities:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X)';

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
     ...
     withCapabilities({ 'browserName': 'firefox',
        userAgent: ua,
        'user-agent': ua,
    }).
    build();
```

There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998162/how-to-change-user-agent-in-selenium-with-net) which says to use a firefox profile, but that's not exposed. There is no `driver.FirefoxProfile` nor one exposed globally nor `webdriver.FirefoxProfile` nor `driver.profiles` etc.

I have tried Googling and looking [the source](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js) and [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) but there is nothing on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* do it with Firefox, but you *can* do it with Chrome. It's undocumented:

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var opts = new chrome.Options();
opts.addArguments(['user-agent="YOUR_USER_AGENT"']);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(opts.toCapabilities()).
    build();
```

Answer (score 5):

I succesfully changed phantom's user agent using [WD](https://github.com/admc/wd) with this code:

```
var capabilities = {
    'browserName': 'phantomjs',
    'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent':  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.11 Safari/537.36'
};
return browser
    .init(capabilities)
...
```

And [this](http://yizeng.me/2013/08/10/set-user-agent-using-selenium-webdriver-c-and-ruby/) link shows how to change firefox's user agent, although the code provided is for C#/Ruby.

Comment: I ran into a problem where an ASP.net server would return broken JavaScript with the default PhantomJS user-agent, so I have to spoof it so I get a correct page. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164753/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanager-is-undefined-error-in-ie11-working-fine-in-ie10

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install the [firefox-profile](https://github.com/saadtazi/firefox-profile-js) package. Here's a snippet:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');

var myProfile = new FirefoxProfile();        
var capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.firefox();

// here you set the user-agent preference 
myProfile.setPreference('general.useragent.override', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36');

// attach your newly created profile 
myProfile.encoded(function(encodedProfile) {
    capabilities.set('firefox_profile', encodedProfile);

    // start the browser 
    var wd = new webdriver.Builder().
        withCapabilities(capabilities).
        build();

    wd.get('http://testingsite.com/');
});
```

Easy peasy!

Comment: I could not reproduce this.

Comment: You don't need that package any more, current selenium-webdriver includes that functionality out of the box.

Comment: see https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox.html

Answer (score 1):

Recent selenium-webdriver versions have added a [feature to specify firefox preferences](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox.html).

```js
import {Builder, WebDriver} from 'selenium-webdriver';
import {Options} from "selenium-webdriver/firefox";

const options = new Options().setPreference('general.useragent.override', '....');
const builder = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox')
      .setFirefoxOptions(options);

const webDriver = this.createClientBuilder().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

for chrome you may make like this:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
.withCapabilities({browserName: 'chrome', chromeOptions: {args:['user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"'] } })
.build();
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is that it is **impossible**.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6189